# PHP - Compare values in 2 Multidimensional Arrays then output all associated values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Trying to compare two Multidimensional Arrays in PHP. Unfortunately, I'm unable to join two tables as the server is MySQL 5.6 and the "fields" table field value is a JSON document as string. ANY help would be much appreciated.

```
   $fields = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'option' =>'Field Label 1',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'option' =>'Field Label 2',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'option' =>'Field Label 3',
        ),
);
    $leads = array(

        array(
            'field_num' => 1,
            'name'=>Eddie,
        ),
        array(
            'field_num' => 3,
            'name'=>Mike,
        ),
        array(
            'field_num' => 2,
            'name'=>Frank,
        ),
        array(
            'field_num' => 2,
            'name'=>Mark,
        ),
        array(
            'field_num' => 2,
            'name'=>Dan,
        ),
);
```

Output should look like this:
Eddie | Field Label 1
Mike | Field Label 3
Frank | Field Label 2
Mark | Field Label 2
Dan | Field Label 2

Here's what I tried. Needless to say, it didn't work.

```
      foreach( $fields as $key => $field ) {
    if ($fields[id] === $leads[$key]['field_num']); {
        $mergedFieldID = $fields[id] === $leads[$key]['field_num'];
         echo $leads[$key]['name'] . "|" . $field['option'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I'm unable to join two tables as the server is MySQL 5.6 and the "fields" table field value is a JSON document as string.*" ... thats a shame. Would have been much cleaner/easier ;)

Comment: I added what I tried in the question. Apologies.

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't work. The index of one array, isn't necessarily the same index as the other arrays sub 'id' item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you rolling:

```
$newarray = [];
foreach($leads as $lead) {
    $key = array_search($lead['field_num'], array_column($fields, 'id'));
    $newarray[] = array($lead['name'],$fields[$key]['option']);// put into new array
    echo $lead['name'] .'|'. $fields[$key]['option'] .'<br>';// or direct output
}
print_r($newarray);
```

Outputs:

```
Eddie | Field Label 1
Mike | Field Label 3
Frank | Field Label 2
Mark | Field Label 2
Dan | Field Label 2

Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Eddie
            [1] => Field Label 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mike
            [1] => Field Label 3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Frank
            [1] => Field Label 2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mark
            [1] => Field Label 2
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dan
            [1] => Field Label 2
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function combine_arrays_by_keys(
    array $array1, 
    string $id1, 
    string $use1, 
    array $array2, 
    string $id2, 
    string $use2
) : array
{
    foreach ($array1 as $value) {
        $temp1[$value[$id1]] = $value[$use1];
    }
    foreach ($array2 as $value) {
        $temp2[$value[$id2]] = $value[$use2];
    }
    $result = [];
    foreach ($temp1 as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = [$temp1[$key], $temp2[$key]];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74b94523078c7cc2e931e0892734b834f3dfa859

Answer (score 0):

If you want try a proper mysql query with join...  looking to your data sample the query for the mysql db should be

```
  select table2.name, table1.option
  from table1 
  inner join table2  on table1.id = table2.field_num
```

this shoudl retunr the result you posted

Comment: That would probably be the most performant solution, however his data is stored in a json encoded format.